# String to Date Conversion in Python

Tags: python, string, numpy, matplotlib, to-date

In the following piece of code:

```
df['Year']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).year
df['Month']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
df['Day']=pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day
df['MM_DD_str']=df['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)+'-'+df['Day'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Since I want only MM-DD i did this way and it is a string now. But later on the program I want them in the date format. Especially I need month in order to plot a graph. Can i extract a date by extracting month from it.

Edited:

I want to plot a graph in which the Xtick should have the months like Jan, Feb, Mar upto Dec. I have to extract month from the dataframe df['MM_DD_str'] and make them as tick labels for the graph.

This is the final code i have written for plotting graph:

```
md_str = df['MM_DD_str']
get_month =md_str.apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, format='%m-%d').month)
#print(get_month)
plt.xticks(get_month,('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'))
plt.show()enter code here
```

I am not getting neither output nor error

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question properly but
the df['date'] column could be used to plot the graph since it is already in date-time format

pd.to_datetime() can be used 
so lets say

```
date='2019-05'
date=pd.to_datetime(date)
date.month
```

EDIT:
Matplotlib needs numeric values to plot on the x axis
when you say plt.xticks() as some string values you cant plot the graph however you can change the labels . so this is an example adjust to your labels

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    figure=plt.figure()
    ax=plt.axes()
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    months=['june','july','august','september']
    dates=['2019-06','2019-07','2019-08','2019-09']
    df['dates']=dates
    df['values']=[1,4,7,10]
    df['dates']=pd.to_datetime(df['dates']) #pd is for pandas
    df['values'].plot(ax=ax)     
    ax.set_xticks([0,1,2,3,4])   #numerical values that get plotted
    ax.set_xticklabels(months)   #actual labels for those numerical values
```

Comment: Can you please tell what error because its not showing any error when i am running it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you currently have a date string, like "06-23" for example, and you later want to extract the month from it as a datetime object:

```
md_col = df['MM_DD_str']
get_month = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, format='%m-%d').month
md_col.apply(get_month)
```

get_month is a lambda function that takes a string, converts it to a datetime object, and then extracts the month.

[.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) takes a dataframe column and applies a function to all the rows in the column

Note that if your column contains NaNs or strings that cannot be converted to dates, you could include the errors argument in the [.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function:

```
get_month = lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d, errors='ignore', format='%m-%d').month
```

Comment: I got this error: 
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series. 
When I tried to print md_str its showing index which is an id and the corresponding date

Comment: but apply() doesnt take axis parameter.Error: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: You probably don't need the axis argument since we've already selected a column on the first line. That might be why it's causing an error. Did you try it without the axis argument?

Comment: yes i tried. Please check the edited code . I tried that way . But I am not getting it

Comment: As @rahul said. There seems to be a problem with "xticks" arguments. Try: xticks(get_month.tolist(), ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'...])